# Ifilter in scipy result is different compare with matlab(use butterworth )

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm woring at convert matlab code to python code.
Now, I have some problem in using scipy.signal.Ifilter.
I generate filter coefficient with butterworth function in python.
When I generate **bandpass** filter coefficient using butter function and filtering with scipy.signal.Ifilter function, the **result is the some with matlab**.
But, I use butter function to generate **highpass** filter and filtering with the Ifilter function, the result is almost some... In my attention, the value are different with 0.005*** between matlab and python.
But, the number of value are 100,000, so the summery different is too big.
In my case, in **matlab the sum of result is 10.0022 and the python result is 6.992**

So, I think the problem is the coefficient which generated by butter function.
I got the coefficient from matlab, and import it to python, but the result of sum is 7.002. I don't understand why make so different result in high pass filter. when I using bandpass filter. The sum of result is almost same.

band pass:

```
Fn = SampFreq / 2.0
Wn = np.divide([FreqCen - Freqband / 2, FreqCen + Freqband / 2], Fn)
b, a = butter(FiterOrder, Wn, 'bandpass')
FiltSignal = sp.signal.lfilter(b, a, Signals)
```

High pass:

```
    Fn = SampFreq / 2.0
    Wn = FreqCut / Fn
    b, a = butter(FiterOrder, Wn, 'high')
    FiltSignal = sp.signal.lfilter(b, a, Signals)
```

Comment: No one can help me ?
I think it's not a float precision problem.

Comment: Can you show the matlab code that you used to generate the filter, and show the values of the matlab highpass filter coefficients?

Comment: Also, please give the values of `SampFreq`, `FreqCut` and `FilterOrder` for the high pass code.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I had add comment to git. Thank you